# using Firebase.Auth; Unity does not recognize this as valid

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I have setup everything that is needed for firebase and google signin to work, however on my script using Firebase.Auth; is greyed out,

Is there something else I need to do for it to see this class?

[image: Code Snippet]

Okay so after doing many more searches on google, I found this on 1 of the help docs

Am I correct to assume I need to add this code somewhere? and if so, how would I go about adding it, as google help docs are somewhat vague when it comes to the actual code and being a noob still, I have no idea how to implement this

```
Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
  var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
  if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available) {
// Create and hold a reference to your FirebaseApp,
// where app is a Firebase.FirebaseApp property of your application class.
   app = Firebase.FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;

// Set a flag here to indicate whether Firebase is ready to use by your app.
  } else {
UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
  "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
// Firebase Unity SDK is not safe to use here.  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete all `.csproj` files in project directory then close the visual studio and open it again.